# How to run an application as root without asking for an admin password?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am writing a program in Objective-C (Xcode 3.2, on Snow Leopard) that is capable of either selectively blocking certain sites for a duration or only allow certain sites (and thus block all others) for a duration. The reasoning behind this program is rather simple. I tend to get distracted when I have full internet access, but I do need internet access during my working hours to get to a number of work-related websites. Clearly, this is not a permanent block, but only helps me to focus whenever I find myself wandering a bit too much.

At the moment, I am using a Unix script that is called via AppleScript to obtain Administrator permissions. It then activates a number of ipfw rules and clears those after a specific duration to restore full internet access. Simple and effective, but since I am running as a standard user, it gets cumbersome to enter my administrator password each and every time I want to go "offline". Furthermore, this is a great opportunity to learn to work with XCode and Objective-C. At the moment, everything works as expected, minus the actual blocking. I can add a number of sites in a list, specify whether or not I want to block or allow these websites and I can "start" the blocking by specifying a time until which I want to stay "offline".

However, I find it hard to obtain clear information on how I can run a privileged Unix command from Objective-C. Ideally, I would like to be able to store information with respect to the Administrator account into the Keychain to use these later on, so that I can simply move into "offline" mode with the convenience of clicking a button. Even more ideally, there might be some class in Objective-C with which I can block access to some/all websites for this particular user without needing to rely on privileged Unix commands. A third possibility is in starting this program with root permissions and the reducing the permissions until I need them, but since this is a GUI application that is nested in the menu bar of OS X, the results are rather awkward and getting it to run each and every time with root permission is no easy task.

Anyone who can offer me some pointers or advice? Please, no security-warnings, I am fully aware that what I want to do is a potential security threat.

Comment: If you use Firefox there is already a plugin called LeechBlock: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476 (of course you have to be disciplined to not use Safari or any other browser ;))

Comment: If you shorten your question to about one short paragraph I'm sure many more people will respond. There's no need to know all the circumstances in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something with admin privileges, and you don't want to have to authenticate each time, it sounds like you need to look at setuid.

Make little command-line executable to do the rule changing, and then set that tool's owner to root. Then, set the setuid bit. Now, you can run it as a user and it will run as root.

Look here for more info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: Setuid shouldn't be used anymore, launchd can replace it. (It's a lot harder to use though.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a separate process that runs with higher privileges. Have a look at the [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) on how to run such helper applications using launchd.

Comment: Yes, this would work too.  It is absurdly complicated though ;)

Comment: @Ken: +1, You're absolutely right, I'm using launchd for one of my applications and it's horrible to work with. (I'm sure it's quite good for simpler tasks though…)

Comment: I think I will prefer the approach of Ken. I tried to work my way through the BetterAuthorizationSample, but is terribly complex for the rather simple task that I am trying to accomplish :).